# Visual basic factorial (Console application)

Tags: loops, visual-studio-2012, console-application

Does anyone have any idea why this code isn't executing properly?

"
Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter any number.")
    Dim num As Integer = Console.ReadLine
    Dim result As Long = 1
    For counter As Integer = num To 1 Step -1
        result *= counter
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("The factorial of the number you have entered is :" + result)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

End Module

"

Answer (score 0):

Just change your plus symbol "+" to an ampersand "&".

The plus symbol is for adding numbers so it's trying to convert your string on the left side of the equation to a double and failing.

The ampersand is for string concatenation.  This causes your result value to be converted to a string and added to your message.